# how to call a function from a switch statement in javascript

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I'm pretty new at javascript so I might not see my problem clearly. I'm trying to create a search bar that simply searches for say, 3 different items. I've already built my function that I am trying to call, but I can't get it to display the function in the switch statements function.

```
function doSearch() { //start doSearch
searchvalue = document.searchbox.searchterm.value 

switch (searchvalue){ //start switch statement
    case "4426": buildProduct(); //this is the part that I can't get to work properly.
                 break
    case "88123": buildProduct();
                  break
    case "2400X": buildProduct();

    default:  alert("Sorry, please try again.")
              break 
 } //end switch statement

} //end doSearch
```

The search box displays fine, and it even alerts the `default` just fine, but when I enter `4426` and click, it does nothing. The only way I have been able to get it to work somewhat is if I add a `document.writeln (buildProduct);` instead of `buildProduct()`.
And the HTML for the form is

```
<FORM NAME="searchbox">
    <INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="searchterm">
    <INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE="Search" ONCLICK="Javascript:doSearch()">
</FORM>
```

EDIT:
This is the full code.

```
function makeHeader() {
     var data = "<B>"
     data +="<H1>Computers for Sale:</H1>"
     data +="</B>"
     return(data)
}
function makeFooter() {
     var data = "<B>"
     data +="<small>Copyright 2013 ComputersforSale</small>"
     data +="</B>"
     return(data)
}
function buildProduct(prodName, prodID, prodDescription) { //start buildProduct
var data ="<TABLE style='width:100%' BORDER=1 CELLPADDING=10><tr><td>" 
data += makeHeader()
data += "</td></tr>"
data += "<tr><td>"
data += prodName + '</br>' + prodID + '<br>' + prodDescription  
data += "</td></tr>"
data += "<tr><td>"
data += makeFooter()
data += "</td></tr>"
data += "</table>"
return(data)
document.writeln(buildProduct)
document.close()

} //end buildProduct

function doSearch() { //start doSearch
searchvalue = document.searchbox.searchterm.value
switch (searchvalue){ //start switch statement
case "4426":
  buildProduct();
  break;

case "88123": 
  buildProduct();
  break;

case "2400X": 
  buildProduct();
  break;

default: 
  alert("Sorry, please try again.")
  break;
} //end switch statement

} //end doSearch
```

The HTML links for the function:

```
<a href= "Javascript:buildProduct('HP 4426', '4426','Newest and Best Laptop from HP Computer')">Item #1 HP 4426</a></br>
<a href= "Javascript:buildProduct('IBM 88123 ThinkPad', '88123','IBM micro Laptop Computer')">Item #2 IBM 88123 ThinkPad</a></br>
<a href= "Javascript:buildProduct('Dell Dimension 2400', '2400X','A fast 2.4 ghz computer, 80 GB HD, 256 Meg, CDRW and DVD.')">Item #3 Dell Dimension 2400</a>
```

Comment: What does buildProduct() look like? It could be a bug in that function.

Comment: You have missing semicolons, undeclared global variable, messy indenting, not sure what's wrong with it but I'd start fixing those issues first. Then try debugging your code with the console and see if it gives any errors.

Comment: So you don't actually have a `switch`, but instead you have links. In that case, you're not doing anything with the HTML markup you're building, as I stated in my now deleted answer. I have no idea what you expected would happen to the HTML string, but right now you're just ignoring it.

Comment: Yeah I have the links that build a document so I can view them which works fine. But now I want to make a search bar that can search for the item and will then go to the same document I set up when I clicked on the link, but I can't seem to figure that part out.

Answer (score 4):

I think **break need semicolon(;)** in switch statement

Comment: I've fixed the break; and the other semicolons, but it still does not work.

Comment: No, OP's `break` is fine without a semicolon

Comment: @Leesh: check it out this function buildProduct(prodName, prodID, prodDescription), it takes three parameter. But when you called from switch statement void method buildProduct() is called... It never called coz it requires 3 parameters...

Answer (score 1):

You forgotten to `break` in `case "2400X"` and also break need `;`

```
   function doSearch(){
        searchvalue = document.searchbox.searchterm.value 
        switch (searchvalue){
            case "4426":
            buildProduct(); //this is the part that I can't get to work properly.
            break;

            case "88123": 
            buildProduct();
            break;

            case "2400X": 
            buildProduct();
            break;

            default: 
            alert("Sorry, please try again.")
            break; 
        }
    }
```

Comment: No, OP's `break` does not need a semicolon.

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand the problem.  Consider this block of code:

```
    switch (expression) {
        case expression:

            break;
        default:

    }
```

Your case expression needs to match the value that the switch expression expects.

So, if run the following code:

```
var minerals = ['dirt', 'rock', 'gold'];

for (var i = 0; i < minerals.length; i++) {

    var mineral = minerals[i];

    switch (mineral) { // this will see a string value, in this example, for each item of the array
        case isGold (mineral):
            console.log('We struck gold!')
            break;
        default:
            console.log('No gold found. :(')
    }

}

function isGold (mineral) {
    if (mineral === 'gold') {
        return 'gold'; // this needs to match what the switch expression sees, which is a string in this case, not a Boolean.
    }
}
```

This will be the output:

```
// -> No gold found. :(
// -> No gold found. :(
// -> We struck gold!
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) (Immediately Invoked Function Expression)** if the function is not required in another places (just to avoid duplicate code). And you wont need to add break as the IIFE will return immediately.

```js
function reducer (state,action) {
    switch (action.type) {
      case 'increment':
        (function () {
          // do something
        })()
      case 'decrement': 
        return {count: state.count - action.payload}
      case 'reset': 
        return init(action.payload)
      default: 
        throw new Error();
    }
  }
```